# Assigning to a Range ignores the type of data being assigned - workarounds?

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a variant array (that is, the elements can be various types) and assign the array to the Range.Value (or constants to Range.Formula) property then Excel will automatically convert the values being passed into a 'best-guess' type based on the destination cell's NumberFormat.

For example, in the below all 'numbers stored as strings' (intentionally) will be converted to numeric types if they are assigned to a cell with the "General" number format.

```
Sub foo()

    Selection.Value = Array( _
        100, _
        "100", _
        "A Cat", _
        "2012-05-02", _
        "36.4")

End Sub
```

In other words, Range.Value = Range.Value does **not round-trip** as type-information in the data being assigned back is ignored on the assignment back to Range.Value, with only the Range.NumberFormat controlling its interpretation.

Are there any good workarounds to prevent or deal with this?

The only one I can think of is to iterate through the array, testing if it is a string and adding an apostrophe in front if it is. This has an undesireable side-effect of the apostrophe actually being present in the workbook (albeit ignored by **Excel** itself for the purposes of Range.Value etc). It is not possible (as far as I know) to assign number formats to cells en-masse based (otherwise one could prepare an array that has the number formats of the data to 'pre-load' the cells with the correct number format).

I use arrays and collections frequently to greatly increase the performance of data processing but I desire, when finally pumping the data out, to preserve the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by putting an apostrophe in front of any text values:

```
Sub foo()

    Selection.Value = Array( _
        100, _
        "'100", _
        "A Cat", _
        "'2012-05-02", _
        "'36.4")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a workaround, albeit this was my first thought as well ("The only one I can think of is to iterate through the array, testing if it is a string and adding an apostrophe in front if it is"). Perhaps this is the only solution.